# How do restorationist Christian churches cooperate with mainstream Christian churches?

Tags: christian-living, inter-faith

It's not hard to see how mainstream and nondenominational Christian churches cooperate with each other: it's common for them [come together](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/17181/what-christian-denominations-do-not-require-belief-in-mainstream-christian-core) in community, charities, and many points of doctrine. This is refreshing, because there are many resources and discussions about the *differences* within Christianity. [Some Christian churches even have classes about other ones.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6826/why-do-some-christian-churches-have-classes-about-other-churches)

How do restorationist Christian churches, which typically fall outside the notion of *mainstream* for their notably different/augmented beliefs, cooperate and coincide with other Christian faiths? What are their shared values?

In your answer, feel free to comment on lifestyle, culture, community involvement, service, morality, doctrine, charities, humanitarian efforts, missionary work, etc. You may mention specific restorationist churches using reliable citations (and official sources if possible).

Comment: My experience is that there is no cooperation with evangelical Christians. There's probably unwillingness on both sides.

Comment: Not all restorationist churches are non-mainstream (i.e. disagreeing with fundamental Christian doctrine), unless they are so by the operational definition of "mainstream."

Comment: For those not familiar with the term see [What's the basic premise behind "restorationist" movements?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/16852) and perhaps [this answer](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/16579/30) to an unrelated question that touches on the terminology.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll get broad differences of opinion on such a question. On the one hand, two churches may work together on a project which both agree is worthwhile despite differences in doctrine on the grounds that as long as we both agree on the goal, we can co-operate. Others refuse to work with other churches that differ from them by some sufficient degree because they don't want to give the impression that they are endorsing these beliefs, or that these beliefs do not matter.

Evangelicals and Catholics have frequently worked together on the pro-life movement and on religious freedom issues. But I'm hard pressed to think of other examples.

This certainly isn't a new issue. Recall the Puritans and the Separatists in the 1600s: they had similar beliefs, but the Puritans believed that the strategy should be to reform the established church, while the Separatists said that they should separate and form their own churches.

Comment: Is it clear from my question that there's a difference between restorationist and reformist? (I'm not sure how widely known the term is.) This answer is good, though a bit broad (granted, I leave it open in the question), but I'm specifically asking about restorationist groups.

Answer (score 0):

Proposition 8 in California saw members from many different church groups come together in the defence of traditional marriage.

Comment: This is the start of what could be a great answer. Could you expand on this idea/train of thought and maybe add some citations?